# Regex for particular section of content

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I wanted to write a JavaScript regex for the following text:

> If you’re curious about this, it’s a garbled quotation from
>   Cicero’s De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum (On the Ends of Good and Bad),
>   book 1, paragraph 32, which reads, “Neque porro quisquam est, qui
>   dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit,”
>   meaning, “There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it
>   and wants to have it, simply because it is pain.” The book was popular
>   during the Renaissance, when the passage was used in a book of type
>   samples for that wonderful new technology, printing.

If the regex matches `Bonorum`, it should capture all the content after the `Bonorum` text until `passage`.

I'm trying with `(issue\s+date)(.*?)excluding`, but it is not working

Thank You

Comment: I don't think the text contains `issue` or `date` or `excluding` right?

Comment: Did you mean to use a pattern like `\bBonorum\b(.*?\bpassage\b)`  https://regex101.com/r/V33ZGF/1 or https://regex101.com/r/LraTZ3/1

Comment: Yes but your regex is not working

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific than that. Did you see the demo links? Are that not the expected matches? Did you check the posted answer?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I had checked but it is not working in my set of string

Comment: You could update the question adding the code and the text that you are using with the expected matches.

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/QOpzz5/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BkyR2q/3/)

```js
let s =  "If you’re curious about this, it’s a garbled quotation from Cicero’s De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum (On the Ends of Good and Bad), book 1, paragraph 32, which reads, “Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit,” meaning, “There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain.” The book was popular during the Renaissance, when the passage was used in a book of type samples for that wonderful new technology, printing.";
let regex = /(?<=Bonorum ).*?passage/;
let result = regex.exec(s);
if (result) {
    console.log(result[0])
}
```

Or you could use `/(?<=\bBonorum ).*?\bpassage\b/` to ensure `Bonorum` and `passage` are on word boundaries, if that is a requirement.

Or use `/(?<=\bBonorum ).*?(?=\bpassage\b)/` if you do not want to include the word `passage` (not entirely clear in the question).